# freecodecamp API takes forever to load, or doesn't load at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JS/Jquery: I thought the problem was because I did not wrap my code in a document.ready(), however I tried doing that and the same problem occurred. Sometimes the weather, temp and image, especially the image, take more than 5 minutes to load. This was created in codepen.

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude, function(json) {
      $("#current-weather").html(json.weather[0].main);
      var temp = json.main.temp;
      var fahtemp = temp * (9 / 5) + 32;
      var celtemp = (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);
      
      $("#temp").text(Math.round(json.main.temp) + " °C");
      $("#image").attr("src", json.weather[0].icon);
      
      $("#fah").on("click", function() {
        $("#temp").text(Math.round(fahtemp) + " °F");
      });
      
      $("#cel").on("click", function() {
        $("#temp").text(Math.round(celtemp) + " °C");
      });
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function(response) {
    $("#location").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
  }, "jsonp");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.ipdata.co"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

API's can have variable speeds depending on the host of the API. There is a chance it has nothing to do with your code, but that it is their server struggling to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your geolocation request is taking a long time.  Look into the [PositionOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions) and add a timeout to the geolocation request.

You might also want to add a max age option to the geolocation request.